# Android Navigation Component Recreates Bottom Navigation Fragments

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-mvvm

Android navigation component replaces fragments present in the app and calls only`onDestoryView()`, but the fragments in bottom navigation get destroyed completely ,`onDestory()` is called.

**The Question is:**
How can I prevent bottom navigation from completely destroying fragments that belong to bottom navigation and not calling `onCreate()` everytime I switch to one of them.

In view pager we had offScreenLimit that hold the fragments without destorying their views.

Comment: are you using bottomnavigation in a activity ?

Comment: @mostafatayebi. yes, I'm using bottom navigation inside my single activity.

Comment: are you using the navigation or just using bottom navigation? I mean nav controller and ... .

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? Thanks!